# Kafka: too many SubsribableChannels and MessageChannels

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am creating an experimental `Spring Boot` application that uses `Kafka` stream-processing software.

This is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(CustomProcessor.class)
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
    // THE REST OF THE CODE
```

This is `CustomProcessor` interface:

```
public interface CustomProcessor {

    @Input("input1")
    SubscribableChannel input1();

    @Output("output1")
    MessageChannel output1();

    // THE REST OF THE CODE(this contains inputs and outputs between 2 and 49)

    @Input("input50")
    SubscribableChannel input1();

    @Output("output50")
    MessageChannel output1();

}
```

Basically, this application will have 50 `SubscribableChannel`-s and 50 `MessageChannel`-s.

I am wondering will that amount of channels make any problems for my application(make it slower, potential errors, etc.) or it will work perfectly fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of channels has no impact on the performance.
However, i wonder what is it that you are creating that requires that many inputs and outputs. That looks definitely like an anti-pattern for microservices.
In other words, i see an architectural issue here, so feel free to share your business requirement and perhaps we can help you find a better solution.

Also, you are using a very outdated API. The annotation such as `@Input/@Output, @EnableBinding, @StreamListener etc` being deprecated.
We have switched to a simpler [functional model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function).

You can also read these two blog posts for additional context:

- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified
- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I know that it is an antipattern, but currently, I am learning Kafka and I was exploring some possibilities in this dummy application.
I will definitely put in mind your advices and read those two articles.